# How to name "perfect" lattice paths

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology

Is there a special name  for lattice paths which visit each lattice point exactly once? [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk#/media/File:Self_avoiding_walk.svg) is an example.

Comment: Looks like a Hamiltonian path to me.

Comment: Looks like an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just dealing with finite lattices (or graphs in general), the term you are looking for is a Hamiltonian path. Infinite lattices (or graphs) will require an extension of the idea of a Hamiltonian path, which depending on its use may be infinite in one direction or two.

Hamiltonian paths that end where they start are called Hamiltonian cycles.